# Numerical solution of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that the nonlinear oscillator $y" + f(y) =0$ is equivalent to the system
$y'= -z $,
$z'= f(y)$
and that the solutions of the system lie on the family of curves
$2F(y)+ z^2 = constant $
where $F_y= f(y)$. verify that if $f(y)=y$ the curves are circle.

=> 
nonlinear oscillator $y" + f(y) =0$

where 
$y'= -z $,
$z'= f(y)$

so that means
$z''+z =0$

for the solution of the system lie on the family of curves, i was thinking

$\frac{d}{dt}[2F(y(t))+z^2(t)]= 2F \frac{dy}{dt} + 2z \frac{dz}{dt}$

$=-2Fz +2zf(y)$

$=-2f(y)z+2zf(y)$

$\frac{d}{dt}[2F(y)+z^2]=0$

$2F(y)+ z^2 = constant $

if $f(y)=y$ , then the differential equation is  $y'' + y =0$, meaning that

$y=A cosx +B Sinx$ and $z=-y'= - A sinx +B cosx$.

are the rotate axes.

$pA^2+qAB+rB^2=1$

$p,q,r$ depends on $x$

choose $x$ such that $q=0$

$pA^2+rB^2=1$

what can i do after that?

can someone please check my first,second and last part of answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, you made a mistake.

You calculated $$\frac{dy}{dt} (F(y)^2 + z^2) = y\frac{dy}{dt} + z\frac{dz}{dt}$$
which is completely untrue.

Instead, try to calculate

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left[2F(y(t)) + z^2(t) \right].$$

If $f(y)=y$, then the differential equation is $y'' + y = 0$, meaning that $y=A\cos x + B\sin x$ and $z=-y'= -A\sin x + B\cos x$.

Comment: which part are you answering? first part or last part? is my solution of the system lie on the family of curves correct?

Comment: I am answering the last part, "can anyone help me how to verify the curves are circles if $f(y)=y$". I will edit my answer for the rest.

Comment: is my first part correct?

Comment: $\frac{dy}{dt}[F(y)^2+z^2]= y \frac{dy}{dt} + z \frac{dz}{dt}$, am i allow to do that. and does $\frac{dy}{dt}[F(y)^2+z^2]= 2F(y)+z^2$ after differentiation?

Comment: I see no reason why the first equation you wrote would be true. Without proof, you can surely not suppose it is.

Comment: i edited my answer. would you please check first and second part

Comment: Still not correct:

$$\frac d{dt}\left[F(y)^2 + z^2\right] = 2F\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dt} + 2z\frac{dz}{dt}.$$

This will get you nowhere, if you ask me. Instead, try to follow my advice.

Comment: is it above equations your advice? can you provide me clear advice.

Comment: Copied from my answer, my advice is to calculate $$\frac{d}{dt}\left[2F(y(t)) + z^2(t) \right].$$

Comment: I have just edited my answer of first and second part. would you please check my answer.